# Can we offload double pointer to GPU using OpenMP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mapping, gpu, openmp

I am new to OpenMP and I am trying to parallelize a simple code with a double loop like this one:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++){
        c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
    }
}
```

The data types of `a`,`b` and `c` are and must stay `double**`.

I tried to convert my code to this:

```
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for collapse(2)\
    map(to: a[0:n][0:n],b[0:n][0:n]) map(from: c[0:n][0:n])
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++){
        c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
    }
}
```

But I get `Aborted (core dumped)`, could somebody help me please?

Comment: You shouldn't use these kind of multidimensional arrays anywhere in performance sensitive regions (independent of CPU or GPU computation). You want your data in one continuous chunk of memory for cache locality, less indirections, less allocations and easier transfer to the GPU as well. Then you index into it like `c[i * j_stride + j]` where `j_stride` is equal or bigger (sometimes one wants some padding for alignment etc) than the `j` extent (`n` in this particular case).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This is a way I managed to make it work but my internship's supervisor wants to also make the 2d array work :'( Would you have a possible solution please?

Comment: The problem with `double**` is that data are possibly not contiguous so you need to map each sub-array separately which is known to be very inefficient since starting a transfer has a petty high latency (eg. at least few microseconds per PCIE transfer command). This is not the only problem: working on non-contiguous array is also inefficient on the GPU side... In fact, this is bigger problem: the computation is memory bound and the PCIE transfer cannot be faster than RAM so the GPU computation will always be slower than a parallel CPU code on all platforms!

Comment: By the way, note that GPU are generally only interesting in two main cases: heavily intensive computations (eg. >50 operations per global load/store), or possibly memory-bound ones without data transfer and with SIMT-friendly accesses (eg. contiguous). Your code require slow transfers and does ~0.33 operation per global load/store which is very very small. Put it shortly: using a GPU in this case is completely useless.

Comment: I am totally ok with you! But I still have to do it with `double**` for learning purposes, to see the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, note that compilers like GCC show explicitly the problem by printing the message: `array section is not contiguous in 'map' clause`.

As said in the comments, you need to transfer every contiguous blocks on the target device manually since OpenMP only support contiguous arrays/structures.

The following code should work but it is **very inefficient**, so **do not use it in an application** unless the goal is to benchmark it:

```cpp
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    double* la = a[i];
    double* lb = b[i];
    double* lc = c[i];

    #pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for \
            map(to: la[0:n], lb[0:n]) map(from: lc[0:n])
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        lc[j] = la[j] + lb[j];
    }
}
```

Note that is should create a kernel for each line which is awful but it would be still very inefficient without that anyway (see the above comments for more information). Note that OpenMP mappers may be used if the number of blocks is known at compile time (and is relatively small).

Comment: It is for benchmarking reasons! Thank you very much it works perfectly!